# Deleting multiple separate lines in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I delete multiple separate lines with the same strings of characters at the beginning and the end of each line, using Notepad++?

They follow a pattern like this:

```
[m1] [c navy] xxxx [/c][/m]
[m1] [c navy] xxxxxx xxxx [/c][/m]
........
```

Answer (score 1):

First open the Replace dialog box (Edit > Replace). Thrn tick "Regular Expression" in the dialog. Now as Find text use `^The Characters At the beginning.*` and replace with nothing. Then notepad++ will remove all the lines beginning with those characters.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it doesn't work. Ịt simply responds with "no occurences were replaces". It even doesn't find any such lines with the characters copied and pasted in the "find what" field.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\[m1] \[c navy].+\[/c]\[/m]\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  \[m1]         # literally [m1], [ have to be escaped as it's a special character for regex
                # a space
  \[c navy]     # literally [c navy]
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
  \[/c]         # literally [/c]
  \[/m]         # literally [/m]
  \R?           # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n), optional
```

**Replacement:**

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]